# Speech recognition in facebook bots

Tags: facebook

Is speech recognition option available in developing facebook bots?

I could not find any document related to speech recognition in developers.facebook.com

But I could see FB has purchased Wit.ai for speech recognition.

Is it under development?

Comment: May I Know who downvoted this question?? How could you downvote my question? I dont really understand. It's a question and not an answer also.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. I do, however, believe there are a lot of promise to come with Wit.ai as you mentioned. I tried out Wit.ai back in June and it was only fundamental conversational AI builder.

As of now, the Facebook Messenger Bot doesn't come with Speech Recognition available. I implemented mine with both **IBM Watson** and **Google Cloud Speech** [in this project](https://github.com/hungtraan/FacebookBot), you can check it out for reference. It works pretty well, of course minus the very long response time (up to 10s for a normal conversation sentence, during which I signal the bot to display the "..." sign)

The solution, unfortunately, is not too optimal at this point. The bot receives the audio URL after the voice message was sent by the user, then my bot has to download that file (which is in pretty low-quality compressed `mp3` format), then do audio conversion to wav/flac for IBM Watson/Google Cloud Speech to process. I have a little [discussion about that round trip & scalability](https://github.com/hungtraan/FacebookBot#discussion) at the end of my Github documentation - hypothetical and not empirically stress-tested though.

Comment: This is biggest obstacle imo. I receive files in audio/mp4 format from Messenger and non of Speech2Text services is handling it out of the box